# Cannot query JSON made dataframe column in PySpark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which i made from a json file. The schema is like this-

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- attributes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- att-a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- att-b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- att-c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- att-d: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- att-e: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- att-f: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- att-g: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- att-h: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- att-i: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- att-j: string (nullable = true)
 |-- customer: string (nullable = true)
```

But when i try to access the contents of the column 'attributes' i get this error -

```
>>> test = spark.sql("select customer, attributes.att-a from df limit 1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 767, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'No such struct field att in att-a, att-b, att-c, att-d, att-e, att-f, att-g, att-h, att-i, att-j; line 1 pos 17'
```

If i use backtick to refer the column i get this error-

```
>>> test = spark.sql("select customer, `attributes.att-a` from df limit 1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 767, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`attributes.att-a`' given input columns: [df.attributes, df.customer]; line 1 pos 17;\n'GlobalLimit 1\n+- 'LocalLimit 1\n   +- 'Project [customer#7, '`attributes.att-a`]\n      +- SubqueryAlias `df`\n         +- Relation[attributes#6,customer#7] json\n"
```

What could be the reason? How can I query this column ?

Comment: Try using backtick when you specifiy the column name.

Comment: @blackbishop tried with backtick. It did not work for me. i added the error in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

As @blackbishop mentioned in comments try to add backtick only for StructField.

```
test = spark.sql("select customer, attributes.`att-a` from df limit 1")
```

For more information on backtick please refer [spark java docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html)